# How to tell what daemons are running?

Tags: linux, centos

I'm running centos 5.8 and am trying to determine what daemons are running.

I'm logged in as the root user but when I type `service --status-all` or `chkconfig --list` I get `bash: service: command not found`.

How can I determine what daemons are running?

Comment: _____________________________ ps?

Comment: @user784637 try to run `type service`  first to determine where the `service` command is located or verify if it actually exists. `chkconfig` does not list running services, it only tells you what has been scheduled run on start up in certain init levels.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `service --status-all` command will do what you want. Based on the `bash: service: command not found` error it sounds like `/sbin` isn't in your `$PATH`. Add it and try again: `export PATH=$PATH:/sbin`

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, try `/sbin/service --status-all`; you probably just have a `$PATH` issue from becoming root via `su` instead of `su -`.

Secondly, `ps` can also give you useful information, as can `netstat -ln`.